# Need help coming up with elegant fix for flaw in my algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I'm practicing for an interview with a major online retailer and am right now trying to come up with an elegant solution for the "median of two sorted arrays" problem. I know of the solutions presented on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_H50Ir-Tves), but I'm trying to write an alternative one. I've written out

```
include <stdio.h>

int M2SA ( int * A, int m, int * B, int n )
{
   /* Returns the median of two sorted arrays A and B of lengths m and n respectively. 
      Assumes A and B aren't both empty. 
   */ 
   int ida = 0, idb = 0, idmed = (m+n)/2;
   while ((ida + idb) != idmed)
   {
     if (A[ida] < B[idb])
        ++ida;
     else
        ++idb;
   }
   return (A[ida] < A[idb] ? A[ida] : B[idb]);
} 



int main()
{
    int arr1 [] = {1, 1, 59, 69};
    int arr2 [] = {-4, 0, 49, 59, 59, 59};
    printf("%d", M2SA(arr1, sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int), arr2, sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int)));
    return 0;
}
```

which prints out the correct answer (`59`), but I realize there's a flaw in that my algorithm only works if `idmed` is not greater than `m` or `n`. For instance, if the arrays are `{1}` and `{69, 293, 393, 1923129}`, then `ida` is equal to `1` after the first iteration of the `while` loop and so the second iteration of the while loop attempts to access `A[1]`. However, I can't think of an easy fix to add to my code. Is there an easy one?

Comment: One also widely used definition of median (for even length series) is to take the arithmetic average of the 2 adjoining numbers around the median as the result. ``median [1;2;3;4] = (2+3)/2 = 2.5``

Comment: You're essentially taking the [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) approach to the problem, which is O(n). So you have to handle the end-of-list condition just as you would with a merge sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an elegant fix to your solution:

```
int ida = 0, idb = 0, idmed = (m + n) / 2;
while (ida < m && idb < n && ida + idb < idmed) {
    A[ida] < B[idb] ? ++ida : ++idb;
}
if (ida == m) return B[idmed - m];
if (idb == n) return A[idmed - n];
return A[ida] < B[idb] ? A[ida] : B[idb];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are basically 3 cases to consider:

1. Neither array has been completely consumed.
2. The first array has been consumed, median is in second array.
3. The second array has been consumed, median is in first array.

The implementation has to be aware of those 3 cases.
Which of the 3 cases is triggered depends on the input data.

For example, if all smaller values are in array 1 and the larger ones in array 2 and the length of array 1 is shorter than length of array 2, the index in array 1 is at array 1 length. So accessing it would not be a good idea.

Here an implementation using a for loop instead of the while. I prefer for loop here as it is easier to see that the loop will eventually terminate.

The main() function contains a set of test cases, which trigger all three above mentioned code paths.

```
int 
m2a
( _In_reads_(s1) const int * a1
, int s1
, _In_reads_(s2) const int *a2
, int s2
)
{
    int mi = (s1 + s2) / 2;
    int ai1 = 0;
    int ai2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mi;i++)
    {
        if (ai1 < s1 && ai2 < s2)
        {
            if (a1[ai1] < a2[ai2])
            {
                ai1++;
            }
            else
            {
                ai2++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ai1 < s1)
            {
                ai1++;
            }
            if (ai2 < s2)
            {
                ai2++;
            }
        }
    }
    int result = 0;
    if (ai1 < s1 && ai2 < s2)
    {
        result = a1[ai1] < a2[ai2] ? a1[ai1] : a2[ai2];
    }
    else
    {
        if (ai1 < s1)
        {
            result = a1[ai1];
        }
        if (ai2 < s2)
        {
            result = a2[ai2];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    {
        const int s1 = 4;
        const int s2 = 4;
        int a1[s1] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int a2[s2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int m = m2a(a1, s1, a2, s2);
        printf("%d\n", m);
    }
    {
        const int s1 = 5;
        const int s2 = 4;
        int a1[s1] = { 5,6,7,8,9 };
        int a2[s2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int m = m2a(a1, s1, a2, s2);
        printf("%d\n", m);
    }
    {
        const int s1 = 4;
        const int s2 = 5;
        int a1[s1] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
        int a2[s2] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int m = m2a(a1, s1, a2, s2);
        printf("%d\n", m);
    }
    {
        const int s1 = 1;
        const int s2 = 5;
        int a1[s1] = { 99 };
        int a2[s2] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int m = m2a(a1, s1, a2, s2);
        printf("%d\n", m);
    }
    {
        const int s1 = 5;
        const int s2 = 1;
        int a1[s1] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int a2[s2] = { 99 }; 
        int m = m2a(a1, s1, a2, s2);
        printf("%d\n", m);
    }

    {
        const int s1 = 5;
        const int s2 = 5;
        int a1[s1] = { 1,1,1,1,1 };
        int a2[s2] = { 1,1,1,1,1 };
        int m = m2a(a1, s1, a2, s2);
        printf("%d\n", m);
    }

    {
        const int s1 = 5;
        const int s2 = 1;
        int a1[s1] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int a2[s2] = { 3 };
        int m = m2a(a1, s1, a2, s2);
        printf("%d\n", m);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Fixed remaining bug. Brain dead beats "elegant". If you have 3 cases it is dangerous to try to hide it. So, the loop´s body also shows the 3 cases...

Comment: Where does the `_In_reads(s1)` notation come from?  It is not all that common.  The leading commas really bug me (I loathe them), but that is to some extent stylistic, so each to their own.

Comment: ``_In_reads(count)`` comes from sal.h. It helps the static code checker to find array bugs and in general annotates arguments and functions in a way accessible to tools. I prefer leading commas to trailing ones as I can simply place 1 comment in a line and be done. With trailing commas it is a tad more fiddling.

Comment: In the last test case, replace the `99` with `3` and you'll find that you have an array bug.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change:

```
if (A[ida] < B[idb])
```

To:

```
if (ida < m && A[ida] < B[idb])
```

And:

```
return (A[ida] < A[idb] ? A[ida] : B[idb]);
```

To:

```
return (ida < m && A[ida] < A[idb] ? A[ida] : B[idb]);
```